# Multi lined value stored in a batch string

Tags: batch-file, clipboard

I have a batch file script that includes a copy to clipboard function

```
echo|set /p="Line 1 line 2 line 3"|clip
paste | command | clip
```

When I paste it, it comes out as

```
Line 1 line 2 line 3
```

is there a way to copy it so when I paste it pastes as:

```
Line 1
line 2
line 3
```

Comment: `(echo Line 1^&echo Line 2^&echo Line 3^&rem/) | clip`?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are `echo`ing a single line. You are therefore getting a single line returned when pasting.

```
(
 @echo line 1
 @echo line 2
 @echo line 3
) | clip
```

The above however will do it line by line and pipe to `clip`

If you want to do it as a one liner:

```
echo line 1^& echo line 2^& echo line 3 |clip
```

As also similarly demonstrated by @aschiphl in the comment.